# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't loop on iPad 1 with iOS 5

Tags: ipad, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a short movie for looping in the background of my view. I use MPMoviePlayerController to play the movie. repeatMode is set to MPMovieRepeatModeOne and this works fine on iPad 2, 3 and in Simulator. On iPad 1 however, the movie loops once and stops right after the second playback. The project is iOS 5 w/o ARC (tested from GM up to 5.1.1).

```
- (void)loadVideo {
    NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movieFileName.m4v" ofType:nil];
    self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr]];
    self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.videoPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    self.videoPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    self.videoPlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.videoPlayer.view setFrame:self.movieContainer.bounds];
    [self.movieContainer addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
}
```

How can I get the movie looping on iPad 1?

Comment: I already have the answer, but I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question, because I have less than 10 something. Please be patient. The essence of the answer is: You have to listen to MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out a lot, I finally found a solution to this problem:

After registering for the notification of changed playback-state MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification, the movie loops endlessly and doesn't stop after the second playback on iPad 1. Keep in mind, that this behaviour didn't take place on iPad 2, 3 or Simulator.

The selector performed for the notification must not be empty. Just assign a bool or something. The extended code from above would be:

```
- (void)loadVideo {
    // Create the controller
    NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movieFileName.m4v" ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    // Configure the controller
    self.videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.videoPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    self.videoPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    self.videoPlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.videoPlayer.view setFrame:self.movieContainer.bounds];

    // Register for notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:videoPlayer];
    self.listeningToMoviePlayerNotifications = YES;

    // Add its view to the hierarchy
    [self.movieContainer addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
}

- (void)moviePlayerNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // Do anything here, for example re-assign the listeningToMoviePlayerNotification-BOOL
    self.listeningToMoviePlayerNotifications = YES;
}
```